# What is wrong with this loop? FprintF in matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I have a loop which is supposed to search through a file and add some text

```
fid = fopen('wave_propagation_var5_alpha1delta1.CPS_001', 'rt+')
fprintf(fid, 'dsadsado')
for i =1:383

            currentline = fgetl(fid)
            currentline = strtrim(currentline)
            if strcmp(currentline, '$$SOLID_ANORMAL')==1
                fprintf(fid, 'hello')
            elseif strcmp(currentline, '$$SOLID_DELTANORMAL')==1
                fprintf(fid, num2str(deltalist(i)))
            else
            end
    i=i+1
end
```

Line 2 appears to print into the file correctly. However I cannot figure out why lines 7 and 9 won't. When I debug the if statement is satisfied and the code goes into both lines and executes them. When I open the target file I don't understand why nothing is happening.

Comment: You are trying to read and write from the same file at the same time... write to a different file than the one you're reading from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @Suever it is not possible to read and write from the same file at the same time. It is necessary to either `frewind` or `fseek` in between reading and writing. This is the solution I have opted for below.

Instead of opening a new file for writing as proposed bu @Suever's answer, it does the following:

1) Reads the existing file

2) Remembers the position to write to using `ftell`

3) Rewinds the file

4) Writes to the position remembered using `fseek` and `fprintf`:

```
  fid = fopen('wave_propagation_var5_alpha1delta1.CPS_001', 'rt+')
    while ~feof(fid)
        currentline = fgetl(fid)
        currentline = strtrim(currentline)
        if strcmp(currentline, '$$SOLID_ANORMAL')==1
            alphaline = ftell(fid)
        elseif strcmp(currentline, '$$SOLID_DELTANORMAL')==1
            deltaline = ftell(fid)
        else
        end
    end

    frewind(fid)
    fseek(fid,alphaline,0)
    fprintf(fid, 'hello')
    frewind(fid)
    fseek(fid,deltaline,0)
    fprintf(fid,num2str(deltalist(i)))
```

While @Suever's answer is completely valid and acceptable, I prefer this way because it takes full advantage of the `rt+` permission for reading *and* writing. It bypasses the need to create another file to write to, and simply uses the already existing file making the necessary changes to it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to try to actively read and write from the same file in MATLAB. You'll instead want to use a different file for your output.

```
fin = fopen('wave_propagation_var5_alpha1delta1.CPS_001', 'rt+');
fout = fopen('wave_propagation_var5_alpha1delta1.CPS_001.out', 'w');

for i =1:383
    currentline = fgetl(fin)
    currentline = strtrim(currentline)
    if strcmp(currentline, '$$SOLID_ANORMAL')==1
        fprintf(fout, 'hello')
    elseif strcmp(currentline, '$$SOLID_DELTANORMAL')==1
        fprintf(fout, num2str(deltalist(i)))
    end

    % Print a newline every time to get correspondence
    fprintf(fout, '\n')
    i=i+1
end

fclose(fin)
fclose(fout)

% Replace the input file with the output file if you want
movefile('wave_propagation_var5_alpha1delta1.CPS_001.out', ...
         'wave_propagation_var5_alpha1delta1.CPS_001');
```

Comment: yes but this will print to a different position in the output file than in the input file, correct? lets say the line where '$$SOLID_ANORMAL' occurs is way down there, like line 200. When it gets detected by the if statement and i print to fout it will print at the current position in fout which is different from the current position in fin.

Comment: Also in that case why in the Matlab documentation does it provide an option for fopen with reading AND writing (r+)? If it is a bad idea why are they including it as one of the permissions?https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#inputarg_permission

Comment: @user32882 Then print a newline every time. See update.

Comment: @user32882 It's fine to read and write from a file. You just don't want to do both *at the same time*. You are interleaving the two operations which is going to cause issues with both.

Comment: Im not convinced. Then what is the point of having 'r+' permission. How is it different from 'r' permission. The way you have it coded theres no point making it 'rt+'. We can just make it 'r' and it will work... See what Im saying?

Comment: @user32882 The point is that you can have one file handle, read from it, `frewind` it, and then `fwrite` to it. Does the above code work? If it does, that's literally the only thing I changed, therefore that was the problem.